# How to get parent element in jQuery when child element is known?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile which creates a lot of the DOM for you.  I need to remove() radio buttons, but based on how the HTML is constructed in jQuery Mobile, I do not have an id for the parent div.  I can easily grab both the input and labels, but need to also get rid of the our div to completely removed the entry styling from the list of radio buttons.

```
<div class="ui-radio">
  <input type="radio" value="ahBkMj" id="ahBkMj" name="spam" data-theme="c">
  <label for="ahBkMj" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">Foo</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-radio-off"></span>
    </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: why not toggle them? show/hide?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Will jQuery's [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) do ?

Comment: also of interest may be ".closest()"

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about parent.

Comment: `.parent()` was there before jquery. It is a method of DOMelement object in JavaScript.

Answer (score 12):

Since the `<div>` element is the immediate parent of your `<input>` element, you can use the aptly-named [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method:

```
$("#ahBkMj").parent().remove();
```

In the general case, if you want the first ancestor matching a selector, you can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$("#ahBkMj").closest("div").remove();
```

Note, however, that `closest()` includes the element itself in its search.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me.....

var child = '# or . and name of your child div... ';

```
var width = Math.round($(child).parent().width());
```