# How do I get the container of a component using javascript? - HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say that I want to know what is the container of a dropdownlist using javascript, how can I achieve this?

I have several textboxes on many divs, what I want to do is to which div the textbox that gave the error corresponds.

I want to know if there is something like `$("#textboxid").getContainer`? through JQUERY or any other library that can do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205878/how-to-get-parent-element-in-jquery-when-child-element-is-known

Comment: Yes. Some study of the jQuery site and APIs might be a good place for you to start. Better yet, some basic study of Javascript and DOM manipulation (as you can do this without any jQuery at all, if you understand how the DOM works). Search "get parent of an HTML element" on google and see if that gives you any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With basic javascript features: `document.getElementById("textboxid").parentNode`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for

```
$("#textboxid").parent()
```

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery Parent API](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) for examples

```
$("#element").parent();
```